# Java constructor calling with parameters

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

I am trying to call a constructor in the Student.java with two parameters as follows:

```
public class InheritanceDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s = new Student(String SSname, int SSStudentID);}
    s.writeOutput();
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student extends Person{
    public Student(String Sname, int SStudentID) {
        super(Sname);
        StudentID = SStudentID;
    }

    public void writeOutput() {
        System.out.println("Name:" + getName());
        System.out.println("StudentNumber:" + StudentID);
    }
```

Person.java

```
public Person() {
    name = "No name yet";       
} 
public Person (String initialName) {
    name = initialName;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Here `Person.java` is the base class and `Student.java` is the child class. I am being shown the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line (near `Student s = new Student(String SSname, int SSStudentID);`
    - Syntax error on token "int", delete this 
     token
    - SSStudentID cannot be resolved to a 
     variable
    - String cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token "SSname", delete 
     this token
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Thanks. that helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method (or a constructor), you should pass actual values or variables :

Change :

```
Student s = new Student(String SSname, int SSStudentID);
```

to something like :

```
Student s = new Student("SomeName", 1234);
```

Beside that, I don't see in the code you posted where you declare the `StudentID` and `name` member variables.

Your `Student` class should have (in addition to its current content) :

```
public class Student extends Person { 
    private int StudentID;
}
```

Your `Person` class should have (in addition to its current content) :

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your main function You need to declare the variables `SSname and SStudentID` outside the calling constructor.

Do the following

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ Student s = new Student(String SSname, int SSStudentID);}
s.writeOutput();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
String SSname = "your_name";
int SSStudentID=10;
Student s = new Student(SSname,SSStudentID );}
s.writeOutput();
}
```

Your error will subside then